# FileSystemObject lost in DCOMCNFG

Tags: dcom, filesystemobject

I want to use FileSystemObject, but it lost in DCOMCNFG, I have register it through the command "regsvr32 scrrun.dll".

Any other ways to get it in DCOMCNFG ?

Comment: That is the way to register the COM objects. The installer or repairer for windows might be able to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got a way to sovle this issue.

We need to modify registry to complete it

Run [regedit] -> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\AppID -> create a new key "{0D43FE01-F093-11CF-8940-00A0C9054228}" -> add String value (name: "DLLSurrogate", data:blank)